# Change Label depending on boolean JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding, label

I am super new to JavaFX and for my checkers game I want to display who's turn it is above my board. I have read through multiple very similar questions, but it doesn't seem to get me where I want to go. I hope you can help me!

I have a FXML file with the following code:

```
<HBox fx:id="topBox" alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="10.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.SampleController">
     <children>
        <Label fx:id="labelTurn" text="test" />
        <Button fx:id="buttonResign" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doResign" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Resign" />
     </children>
  </HBox>
```

In my main:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    Checkers content = new Checkers();
    BorderPane border = new BorderPane(); 

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        try {
            border.setTop(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        border.setCenter(createContent());
        Scene scene = new Scene(border);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Checkers from main");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
public class SampleController {
    @FXML
    private Label labelTurn;

    @FXML
    private HBox topBox;

    @FXML
    private Button buttonResign;

    private Checkers content = new Checkers();

    @FXML
    void doResign(ActionEvent event) {
        content.resign();
        // System.exit(0); //TODO eine tatsächliche Methode eingeben!!

    }

    public void setLabelTurn(Label labelTurn) {
        this.labelTurn = labelTurn;

        String setLabelText() {
        String s = " ";
        if (content.getWhiteTurnPropValue()) {
            labelTurn.setText("White, it is your turn.");
            s = "White, it is your turn.";
            return s;
        } else {
            labelTurn.setText("Black, it is your turn.");
            s = "Black, it is your turn.";
            return s;
        }
    }
    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert buttonResign != null : "fx:id=\"buttonResign\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Sample.fxml'.";
        assert topBox != null : "fx:id=\"topBox\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Sample.fxml'.";
        assert labelTurn != null : "fx:id=\"labelTurn\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Sample.fxml'.";
        labelTurn.textProperty().setValue(setLabelText());
    }
}
```

My game data has a BooleanProperty to show who's turn it is. It gets changed after every successful move.

```
BooleanProperty whiteTurnProp = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);

public BooleanProperty getWhiteTurnProp() {
    return whiteTurnProp;
}

public void setWhiteTurnPropValue(Boolean whiteTurn) {
    this.whiteTurnProp.setValue(whiteTurn);
}

public boolean getWhiteTurnPropValue() {
    return this.whiteTurnProp.getValue();
}
```

As far as I have understood, I need to bind the Label to the value, which I have done in the initialize method. But when I play and the value in my game class changed, the label stays the same. How do I update the label? I think I need to add a change listener to something, but I dont know how to do that and more specifically WHERE.

Thank you so much for your help! I shortened my code a bit and hope it is still not too long.

Best,
Lisa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `initialize`: `labelTurn.textProperty().setValue(setLabelText());` is not a binding, it is a simple set on the property. A really strange one as `setLabelText()` sets the text of the `Label` and also return the string which was set, which value is used again to the text of the `Label`.

You could create a real binding instead:

```
labelTurn.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
    String s = " ";
    if (content.getWhiteTurnProp().get())
        s = "White, it is your turn.";
     else
        s = "Black, it is your turn.";

    return s;
}, content.getWhiteTurnProp()));
```